# want to change herf link and name value of multiple html pages without accessing file manaer or cpanel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 10 html pages which having products details with their prices and discount price.
i want to change those pricing and discount pricing value from those html pages,
is there any way to make one post input box html page which can change values from all html page at one place without accessing any c panel or file manager.
Thanks